# How to Configure GameCenter when app Uploaded to Itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have application that have gamecenter. i create Leaderboard Sets , Leaderboards and Achievements. But when i enable the Gamecenter in app for uploading the app i set the Achievements and when Edit the Leaderboard Sets and Leaderboards and select the already created Leaderboard Sets and Leaderboards i got message "No New Leaderboard Sets have been set up." please help me.

Comment: So you have added the leader board in iTunes Connect and used the same leader board in your code?